# ADA - Count the number of <li> in from 2 <ul> (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 2 `<ul>`and they are part of one dropdown. When I when using NVDA screen reader it counts both the `<ul>` list separately. it should count both.

> when I tabbed into `div`it should screen reader should read 6 list items. but now I am getting 3 items which reads rightSection first, then again saying 3 items reading leftSection.

```
    <ul class=nav>
     <li navItem1>
        <div class="divoOne">
            <ul class="rightSection">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>  

            </ul>

            <ul class="leftSection">
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>  
            </ul>

        <div>
    </li>

   </ul>
```

If i make changes on HTML structure I have to code whole lot of css again. I'm new to ADA. is there a way I can do it with `aria` tags or JavaScript.

Comment: use css's `:nth-child(even)` to style a large list into left and right-looking item

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for [aria-owns](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-owns)

```
<nav aria-owns="rightSection leftSection" role="navigation">
   <ul class="nav">
      <li navItem1>
         <div class="divoOne">
            <ul id="rightSection" class="rightSection">
               <li>1</li>
               <li>2</li>
               <li>3</li>  
            </ul>
            <ul id="leftSection" class="leftSection">
               <li>4</li>
               <li>5</li>
               <li>6</li>  
            </ul>
         <div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```